# Trim Last 3 characters in string with a condition using Power Query in Excel

Tags: powerquery

I have a list of part numbers (as seen in attached image).  I would like to trim the last 2 characters after the second delimiter only if the part number begins with "WN".  All other part numbers can stay their full string length.  As an FYI I'm new to using Power Query.

I was thinking along the lines of using TrimEnd with a condition but have not had luck writing the code to do so. I'm also using Microsoft Excel for Mac (Microsoft 365) if that makes a difference

[image: Image of Part Numbers].

Comment: An if() to test for “wn”, then left() with len() or find))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Power Query should do the job:

`if Text.Start([PartNumber], 2) = "WN" then Text.Start([PartNumber], Text.Length([PartNumber]) - 2) else [PartNumber]`